# Magento Bootstrap React Modal open manually

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, magento2, progressive-web-apps

My Content and Link for Modal comes from Cms how can Bootstrap Modal be opened on an element id click?

Code In Component:

> ```
> <Modal.Body>
>     <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
>     <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
> </Modal.Body> </Modal>
> ```

Code coming from CMS which appears after dom is loaded:

```html
<a href="#" id="setCookies">HERE</a>
```

Now how can we change this.state.showModal value on '#setCookies' element click.

Could it be done using jquery or is there a way to change React states from outside or console?

Comment: Can you show your code? Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does the above help?